# Textbox retains old value before the update process asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The problem is, that I am trying to update my database record trough user's input on a Textbox.
The code below shows

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con1.Open();
        try
        {
            //btn_save.Click += new EventHandler(btn_save_Click);
            rs_id = Session["Res_Id"].ToString();

            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                getcategory();
                getcuisine();
            }
            try
            {

                sitem_id = Session["item_id"].ToString();
                if (sitem_id != "")
                {
                    getitemdata();
                    getaddonprice();
                    getchoiceprice();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default");
        }
    }
 public void getitemdata()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_item where item_id='" + sitem_id + "'", con1);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                string price,status;
                txt_iname.Text = dr["item_name"].ToString();
                txt_desc.Text = dr["item_description"].ToString();
                drp_category.SelectedValue = dr["category_id"].ToString();
                cui_drp.SelectedValue = dr["cusine_id"].ToString();
                price_chk = dr["pos"].ToString();
                status = dr["status"].ToString();
                img_nname = dr["item_uname"].ToString();
                img_dname = dr["item_img"].ToString();
                if (price_chk == "1")
                {
                    chk_price.Checked = true;
                    div_price.Style["display"] = "none";
                    div_choice.Style["display"] = "block";
                    div_addon.Style["display"] = "block";
                }
                else
                {
                    chk_price.Checked = false;
                    div_price.Style["display"] = "block";
                    div_choice.Style["display"] = "none";
                    div_addon.Style["display"] = "none";
                }
                if(status=="1")
                {
                    chk_status.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk_status.Checked = false;
                }
                update_id = "1";
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", ex.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
 public void getaddonprice()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select vname as add_on_name,price as amt from tbl_price_master where item_id='" + sitem_id + "' and type='2'", con1);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid_addon.DataSource = dt;
            grid_addon.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", ex.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
    public void getchoiceprice()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select vname as choice_name,price as amt from tbl_price_master where item_id='" + sitem_id + "' and type='1'", con1);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid_choice.DataSource = dt;
            grid_choice.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", ex.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
 public void update()
    {
        try
        {
            string ch_status;
            if(chk_status.Checked)
            {
                ch_status = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                ch_status = "0";
            }
            string item_uname = txt_iname.Text + "_" + rs_id;
            if (chk_price.Checked == true)
            {
                if(img_res.HasFile)
                {
                    deleteimg();
                    getimg();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("master_crud_b2b", con1);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", txt_iname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@restaurant_id", rs_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuisine_id", cui_drp.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", drp_category.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_img", "Item_Images/" + newFileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", "1");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ch_status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_desc", txt_desc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_uname", item_uname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", sitem_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 21);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    item_id = sitem_id;
                    deleteprice();
                    price_insert();
                    price_insert2();
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("master_crud_b2b", con1);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", txt_iname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@restaurant_id", rs_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuisine_id", cui_drp.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", drp_category.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", "1");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ch_status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_desc", txt_desc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_uname", item_uname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", sitem_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 20);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    item_id = sitem_id;
                    deleteprice();
                    price_insert();
                    price_insert2();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (img_res.HasFile)
                {
                    deleteimg();
                    getimg();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("master_crud_b2b", con1);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", txt_iname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@restaurant_id", rs_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuisine_id", cui_drp.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", drp_category.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_img", "Item_Images/" + newFileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", "0");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ch_status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_desc", txt_desc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_uname", item_uname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", sitem_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 21);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    item_id = sitem_id;
                    deleteprice();
                    price_insert3();

                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("master_crud_b2b", con1);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", txt_iname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@restaurant_id", rs_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuisine_id", cui_drp.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", drp_category.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", "0");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ch_status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_desc", txt_desc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_uname", item_uname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", sitem_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", 20);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    item_id = sitem_id;
                    deleteprice();
                    price_insert3();
                }
            }
            Session["item_id"] = null;
            update_id = "0";
            Response.Redirect("Item_List");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", ex.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
```

Now, just to make sure that all is ok, I tried changing the content of the Textbox named txt_desc. To my surprise, upon clicking the save button the content of the txt_desc Textbox returns to its original content.

Thank you.

Comment: Can we see your markup?

Comment: Is the value changed in the database?

Comment: Design Code Sir?

Comment: No Sir. It is picking the Old value due to postback

Comment: @NagaRaj We need your design code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function  `getitemdata()`; is always called. It should be only called on first load of page.

When button is clicked, the data from database is filled again in `text_desc` by this function.

> You should move **all code that fills data** in input fields from database in `!IsPostback`

Like
In your `page_load()`

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
        getcategory();
        getcuisine();
        getitemdata();
 }
```

Also note following:

1. Using `connection` object as global `class` variable can give you connection management troubles at some point. Move it closer to `SqlCommand` usage.
2. Your code is vulnerable to **SqlInjection** attack. Use @`variables` instead of string concatenation for SQL query in `SqlCommand`

Comment: can you please rewrite the page load function sir

Comment: @NagaRaj Why would he rewrite your entire function, he is explaining a core concept that you need to understand to be successful with web forms.

Comment: Ok Ji. I will try It Ji

Comment: Thank You very much Surjit Sir and Greg Sir. Sure Sir i will follow @variable standard Sir. Once again Thank You